# How to prevent Open With dialog from appearing all the time in windows store app?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

When I open a file for the first time, an "open with" dialog appears. I select the desired app with which to open the file and tick the option to always use that app.

When I open the same file a second time, the "open with" dialog appears once more, despite my having ticked the "always use this app" option. How can I go about preventing this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var options = new LauncherOptions();

options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToBeOpened.McmDocument, options);
```

Comment: Isn't that because you set the `DisplayApllicationPicker` to true every time?

Comment: By setting it to true, brings up the OpenWith dialog instead of opening the file with some default app. But in the Open With dialog , there is checkbox which says - Use this app for all .txt files. When I check it, next time when I open a .txt file, the OpenWith dialog should not appear as it should take the app which was selected earlier. Isnt this the ideal beahviour?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe you don't want to set DisplayApplicationPicker = true.

If the user doesn't have a default set then LaunchFileAsync will open the Open With dialog automatically. There is no need to set DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

DisplayApplicationPicker = true explicitely says to ignore the default setting.

The "always use this app" option sets the default to that app so that normal launches (without DisplayApplicationPicker = true) will open the selected app.